# can I have a link to a specific point of an external org file?

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to have a link to a specific heading (e.g. identified by a `CUSTOM_ID` property) of an external org file?
The only relevant example in [the external links section of the manual](http://orgmode.org/guide/External-links.html) seems to be to an org-file as whole (and not to a heading of it).

Comment: You read about and link to 'external links'. There are other types:  http://orgmode.org/guide/Targeted-links.html#Targeted-links

Answer (score 3):

- Go to the place you want your link to point.
- `M-x org-store-link`
- Go to the buffer where you want to have the link.
- `M-x org-insert-link`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have a link to a specific heading...

Yes. The syntax is:

```
file+emacs:full/path/to/file.org::#UniqueCustom_ID
```

where file+emacs ensures emacs opens it another buffer, and the full path to org file gives the filename and org extension. #UniqueCustom_ID comes after the :: to identify the specific heading.

You can look at

```
info:org#External Links
```

for other variations and keyboard shortcuts.